# I can't play without WiFi or hotspot

Tags: pokemon-go

When I use my data for Pokémon GO, no Pokéstops or Pokémon in the sightings appear just the road and the avatar walking however when I use WiFi or hot-spot, the Pokéstops and Pokémon appears again. I have been facing this problem just 3 days ago and I can't play without WiFi or hot-spot. What should I do? I have tried deleting the game and almost everything.

Comment: Hi Jane! Can you view any websites while on data? It sounds more like a Cell Provider issue. :(

Comment: Can you tell us more about what device you're using, are you getting decent signal and able to connect to the internet like normal. This could be a problem with your 3G/4G connection.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the wifi on even if you are using data that helps in gps tracking. On the other note if you are using ios device go to settings>mobile data and check if the data is checked on for Pokemon GO. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be a problem with your provider, not Pokemon go. As mihir said, check your data and make sure it is turned on for pokemon go.  It also might be a problem with your gps or the gps settings. Just my guesses